# plot_ly add trace to 3D scatterplot based on variable

Tags: r, plotly

I'm new to using plot_ly and I am a stuck. I made a 3D scatterplot with coordinates of 2 scores per person. I want to make the dots from the scatterplot have a color based on the timepoints of the score (1st or 2nd score). And I want a line to connect the dots that belong to each person.

I made a plot where the dots are the colour of the participant and the lines are connected properly. However, when I change the colour to the variable that contains the timepoints then the dots are won't connect anymore. I am not sure how to get the dots the colour of the timepoints and keep the lines between the participants dots.

The dataframe:

```
PatientID <- c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4")
Timepoint <- c("1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2")
PC1 <- c(0.5, 1.1, 2.3, 1.6, 0.8, 1.9, 0.9, 1.5)
PC2 <- c(1.9, 2.3, 3.1, 0.9, 2.5, 2.7, 1.3, 3.2)
PC3 <- c(2.1, 2.5, 1.5, 1.3, 1.6, 1.5, 2.1, 2.6)
df <- data.frame(PatientID, Timepoint, PC1, PC2, PC3)
```

Code with lines but dots have participant colour and not timepoints colour:

```
plot_ly(df, x= ~PC1, y= ~PC2, z= ~PC3, type="scatter3d", mode="markers", 
        color = ~PatientID, showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'PC 1'),
                      yaxis = list(title = 'PC 2'),
                      zaxis = list(title = 'PC 3'))) %>% 
  add_trace(mode="lines", split = ~PatientID,
            line = list(color = "black", width = 2), showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image: Lines are good, colours are Pt ID instead of timepoint]

Code with good colour dots but no lines:

```
plot_ly(df, x= ~PC1, y= ~PC2, z= ~PC3, type="scatter3d", mode="markers", 
        color = ~Timepoint, showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'PC 1'),
                      yaxis = list(title = 'PC 2'),
                      zaxis = list(title = 'PC 3'))) %>% 
  add_trace(mode="lines", split = ~PatientID,
            line = list(color = "black", width = 2), showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image: Dots are good colour but now the lines are gone]

Can anyone help me how I can get the right colours and the lines???

Additionally, when I do this with my real dataset the 'Timepoint' somehow doesn't work. The code is the same as above and somehow both dots from each participant gets the same colour when selecting the variable Timepoint as colour.

[image: Colour=Participant and lines are correct]

[image: Colour should be Timepoint however its not correct, and no lines]

If anyone can help me please let me know!

Comment: For the lines when using `color = ~Timepoint`, take the color designation out of `line = list...`, instead use `color = I("black")`. Without seeing the difference in what you referred to as your real data, it's pretty hard to address that issue. Try using a subset of `dput(head(data, 50)` from your actual data, does the issue of incorrect colors persist?